# problem with category menu, it doesn't want to show link

Tags: php, categories, links

I have created a category menu but when it displays in front page it shows just text without link. thats my code:

```
$menuname1 = $lblg_themename1 . 'categorie Menu';
$bpmenulocation1 = 'secondary';
// Does the menu exist already?
$menu_exists1 = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $menuname1 );

// If it doesn't exist, let's create it.
if( !$menu_exists1){
    $menu_id1 = wp_create_nav_menu($menuname1);

// Set up default BuddyPress links and add them to the menu.
wp_update_nav_menu_item($menu_id1, 0, array(
    'menu-item-title' =>  __('Accueil'),
    'menu-item-object' => 'page',
    'menu-item-object-id' => get_page_by_path('accueil')->ID,
    'menu-item-type' => 'post_type',
    'menu-item-status' => 'publish'));

wp_update_nav_menu_item($menu_id1, 0, array(
    'menu-item-title' =>  __('High Tech'),
    'menu-item-object' => 'category',
    'menu-item-type' => 'taxonomy',
    'menu-item-status' => 'publish'));

wp_update_nav_menu_item($menu_id1, 0, array(
    'menu-item-title' =>  __('Geek'),
    'menu-item-object' => 'category',
    'menu-item-type' => 'taxonomy',
    'menu-item-status' => 'publish'));

wp_update_nav_menu_item($menu_id1, 0, array(
    'menu-item-title' =>  __('Web'),
    'menu-item-object' => 'category',
    'menu-item-type' => 'taxonomy',
    'menu-item-status' => 'publish'));

wp_update_nav_menu_item($menu_id1, 0, array(
    'menu-item-title' =>  __('Science'),
    'menu-item-object' => 'category',
    'menu-item-type' => 'taxonomy',
    'menu-item-status' => 'publish'));

// Grab the theme locations and assign our newly-created menu
// to the BuddyPress menu location.
if( !has_nav_menu( $bpmenulocation1 ) ){
    $locations1 = get_theme_mod('nav_menu_locations');
    $locations1[$bpmenulocation1] = $menu_id1;
    set_theme_mod( 'nav_menu_locations', $locations1 );
}
}
enter code here
```

Comment: @sakibmoon do you have an idea about this. thank you firstly

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any other way to resolve this problem. i tried a lot of thing to add link to the category menu but without any success.